# what are the dependent and independent factors and categorical for below project

Tags: distributions, self-study, spss, feature-selection, self-organizing-maps

my project is identification of factors influencing motor bikes for home to office trip. there are some attiributes like gender,age,marital status,education qualification,job type,working sector, no. of members in household,working members in household,monthly income,total household income,no. of motor bikes,members having motor bike driving licence(D.L),no. of cars,members having car D.L,do you have D.L for motor bike, do you have D.L for car,type of house, live-in status of house, do you work from home, do you use internet for office purpose, no. of days you work from house,purpose of trip, timings of office i.e., starting and ending time, vehicle for above trip,distance from home to office,time from home to office and office to home,reason for preferring to private vehicle,likely fare (if you go by bus or shared auto),drop off any kid to school while going to office,does the school come on your way to office, spouse is working person,do you drop off your spouse to her office,city bus is accessible to your house,walking distance from home to bus stop,waiting time at bus stop... and some of these questions are related to one another like spouse is working ?? if no he should not fillup the next question. also like drop off any kid to school.. wat should i use in the related question...wheather '-' (or) 9999...also i am totally confused about the dependent and independent and categorical variables........ also wat the model we are going to use for this project wheather binary logistic (or) multinomial logistic ...

Comment: Please see our [faq] for ways to improve this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to get dinged for having this question be far too open ended, vague and rambling.  It sounds like you're pretty confused about the basics of regression.  I would start with the wiki page about regression:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

There are also a number of books which explain regression and different types of regression (linear, non-linear, poisson, logistic, etc) that you can start reading. I don't know what your math background is, but maybe something like:

[http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Linear-Regression-Models--Student/dp/0073014664/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1363750258&sr=1-2&keywords=linear+regression](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073014664)

might be a decent book to read.  There's simply no way to go into answering your question given the amount of detail and length that would be needed.  The answer would need to be a book in itself.